# Portableapps cannot download firefox updates

Tags: firefox, thunderbird, updates, portable-apps

I **cannot** update Mozilla Firefox (from v.60 to the current) with **method #1**: from *PortableApps launcher* -> *Apps* -> *Check for updates*.

I **cannot** either update with **method #2**: download the `paf.exe` installer, for a local installation from *PortableApps launcher* -> *Apps* -> *Install a new app (paf.exe)*, or extracting as mentioned [here](https://superuser.com/a/1360479/245595).
(I guess this issue is related with the above).
Whenever I try this download, it gets stuck at `Waiting for download3.portableapps.com...`:

[image]

I **can** update FF with **method #3**: from within FF, with *Three bars* -> *Help* -> *About Firefox* -> *Restart to update Firefox*, so this would be a workaround.

I **can** update other PortableApps (e.g., KiTTY) with any of methods 1/2.

I **cannot** update Mozilla Thunderbird with method 1, but I could use method 2.

**What could the problem be?**

**As a workaround (even if not my final target), how can I get an URL for the `paf.exe` that will work with `wget` for a direct download?**

---

[This](https://portableapps.com/node/57916) topic is related, but with the following differences:

1. I have the problem with either PortableApps Platforms 15.0.2 and 16.0 Beta 2. For these releases the issue is presumably fixed.
2. I checked other apps that presumably had problems with Platform 14.4.3:
   Firefox, 4stAttack, AIMP, and others as well. The only one that I cannot update/install (so far) is Mozilla FF.

---

Note: Perhaps this (posted by me) is related:
https://superuser.com/questions/1364101/firefox-gives-your-connection-is-not-secure-chrome-works-fine

Comment: @sancho.s Do you want to make portable Firefox or want a solution with Portable Apps Platform? I can provide a solution with the first method.

Comment: @Biswapriyo - I mean to get a solution with the Portableapps Platform. Please see updated OP.

Comment: Updating Firefox through PortableApps fails since at least [4 years ago](https://portableapps.com/comment/226727#comment-226727). However, it's easy enough to update portable Firefox by using the non-portable download, see [link](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/internet/firefox/update-portable-firefox-the-easy-way/). Would you accept this as an answer?

Comment: @harrymc - The link is ~11 years old (but not necessarily invalid). In that sense, I wonder: 1) if it still applies, 2) if it is exactly equivalent to methods 1/2, 3) if it is any different from method 3...

Comment: I don't use PortableApps, so the link needs testing.

Comment: I use PortableThunderbird, and it's usually a matter of time before regular new versions are "ported" to portable format, so you can check for updates via the hamburger icon in the top right corner of Firefox, then Help, then About Firefox. If there IS an update pending, you'll be able to download and install it this way. PortableFirefox.exe is just an application launcher, it's not Firefox per se.

Comment: @Didier - This is method #3, which I can already do. Thanks

Comment: I usually do the same, but then I haven't installed the PortableApps program, I install standalone software when it suits me, so maybe it works differently when you download them via the PortableApps application itself.

Comment: Does updating Portable Firefox with the non-Portable Firefox work and is acceptable?

Comment: @Biswapriyo - Please post an answer so I can vote/award if appropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per comments received, nobody found:

1. How to update Portable Firefox from the PortableApps platform 
   (method #1 in the question).
2. How to get a direct download link for `PortableFirefox.paf.exe`, for `wget`, e.g.
   (method #2 in the question).

So the two possible workarounds (the best approach to an answer, even if not the target of the question) are:

1. To update FF from within FF
   (method #3 in the question).
2. To use the non-portable version of FF, see [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1538971/245595).

Answer (score 0):

Reports that updating Firefox through PortableApps fails have been around
since many years. For example,
[this comment](https://portableapps.com/comment/226727#comment-226727)
from 2016:

> I've been updating Firefox from within the program for a while because updating through PortableApps fails. It reports "Connecting..." until it times out. Same problem with Thunderbird. Other programs have updated successfully.

An alternative to updating from within Firefox is to download the non-portable version
from the Mozilla website.
The article
[Update Portable Firefox the Easy Way](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/internet/firefox/update-portable-firefox-the-easy-way/)
from 2009 describes the method. This requires using the Custom method of installation
for specifying the folder and disabling all extra actions such as installing
desktop icons.

Comment: As said, I awarded the bounty, and posted a more encompassing answer referencing to this.